# Passing table without parentheses in lua giving error

Tags: lua, lua-table

The following gives me an error 'syntax error near 'Person' even though in the faq (http://www.luafaq.org/) it stats: "so it cleverly uses the fact that Lua will accept single function arguments without parentheses if the argument is a string or a table"

```
function class(cls)
   return cls
end

Person = {}

class Person

print(Person)
```

What am I missing here? If I change class Person to class "Person" it works, but the faq stats it should work with both strings and tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parentheses can only be omitted when there is only one argument, and the argument is a string literal or a table constructor.

In your example, syntactically, you can call `class 'foo'` or `class {}`, but not `class Person`, because `Person` is a variable, not a table constructor.

Comment: Ah interesting. The FAQ didn't say table constructor but just table. That's a bummer. Thanks.

Comment: @user441521, the manual says explicitly:  `args ::= tableconstructor` at http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.9 and http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10.